# (c++)OpenGL и glfw - приключения на мою голову

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

еееее.Проблемы начались СРАЗУ.Я даже не начал программировать.Ну объясните мне (возможно я покажусь тупым) что это за glfw.Нет,ну я понял, что мы создаем графику с помощью glfw, **используя** openGL.Так нафига glfw(боже),если есть openGL???(вчера начал темой интересоваться)

P.S что есть кроме glfw?И какие варианты лучше?

Comment: слишком сложные для меня намеки...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если просто:

GLFL позволяет открыть пустое окно, и выполнять с ним кое-какие действия, например получать ввод с клавиатуры/мыши.

OpenGL позволяет рисовать в уже готовое окно, но сам никаких функций для открытия окна не имеет.

---

> что есть кроме glfw

Есть SDL2. В нем больше полезных функций, но интерфейс с непривычки может показаться не таким удобным.

Comment: черт побери, а я уж испугался...

Comment: а OpenGL от Qt?

Comment: qt - gui, да и мне кажется посерьёзнее будет